# Convert fraction to decimal in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to convert fraction to decimal with minimal number of repeating decimal places in brackets. It should look like this:

for `n=100, m=5` output should be `20`

for `n=184, m=5` output should be `36.8`

for `n=1, m=3` output should be `0.(3)`

for `n=11, m=24` output should be `0.458(3)`

for `n=100, m=7` output should be `14.(285714)`

My program is failing for the last fraction (100/7). What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me?

This is my code:

```
Program fraction2decimal(output);
var n,m,remainder: integer;

begin
  read(n,m);
  d := 0;
  write (n div m);
  remainder := n mod m;
  if remainder <> 0 then write('.');
  while remainder <> 0 do
  begin
    if remainder = (remainder*10 mod m) then write('(');
    write (remainder*10 div m);
    if remainder = (remainder*10 mod m) then begin 
      write(')');
      break;
     end;
end;
    remainder := remainder*10 mod m;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
 if remainder = (remainder*10 mod m)
```

line only checks for one digit repeats. You need to check for multiple lengths of repeating digits. Obviously the 100/7 was added to the exercise for just that.